# Cloudant Query or Map/Reduce when getting latest documents

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

My Cloudant database has several types with several documents of each type. The documents have a timestamp field. Let's say the types are "A", "B" and "C". I want to get only latest of each type and not all of the documents. In other words, I only want three documents.

This result will then be synced with Pouchdb in the browser.

Do I use Cloudant Query or Map/Reduce?

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to solve it. You can use either Cloudant Query or map/reduce in your case, but Cloudant Query is probably simpler.

Your index will look something like this:

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": ["type", "timestamp"] 
  }
}
```

Then your query will be:

```
{
  "selector": {"type": "A"},
  "sort": [{"timestamp": "desc"}],
  "limit": 3
}
```

If you want an easy way to play around with the Cloudant Query Language, check out [the pouchdb-find demo page](http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/).

Comment: Misunderstood the problem. This solution gives me the latest three of the same type. Looking for the latest of each of three different types. Looks like I'd have to run three different queries. Running different queries gets hard when in the real world I don't know how many different types there are. I'll have to look at a reduce function.